# AWS Data Transfer issue

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i've spot the problem in my AWS cloud.
I'm getting to big bill for Data transfer(month data transfer out).
My EC2 instance contains Tomcat server for mobile application. We have 1.5k users only and we use rest webservices. I've setup benchmarks and they showed that i send 1 - 3gb per month as responses.
But i got a bill for about 9.5 TB data transfer out. Few days ago i was monitoring instance and i see that my server output trafic is approx 200gb/day.
I don't know, maybe i was hacked, but i always use security groups on AWS and users have access for 80 port only and my IP has access to 22(SSH) only.
Can someone help to find a solution? Or maybe someone have suggestion what it can be?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using multiple instances? Are you using a private or public ip to connect between instances?

Comment: No, it's a single instance. This serves has no connection between other servers. But on other instances we use private ip always.

Comment: In this case, if cloudwatch does not show high transfer rates (you can look at up to the last two weeks). Then the cause is probably s3. Enable logging on your buckets and take a look at the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd enable [access logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html) on tomcat, and ensure that this isn't data coming out of tomcat. You should be able to sum up the amount of traffic from the access logs and determine if tomcat is the source.

I assume that you don't have `apache` in front, and that you're using an `Elastic Load Balancer` to translate from 80 to 8080? If you do have `apache` or similar in front, then also enable access logging on that. Don't be running tomcat as root on port 80.

What other components are you using in your setup? Check this isn't some automated backup solution!

Hope this helps,

Comment: We don't use Elastic Load Balancer on this server, so i think it will be much easier to find out if tomcat is the source. In this project we use internal DB and S3. S3 contains a lot of small files and i'm sure it's not a problem. So, i hope access logging will help. I will tell you what i figure out by Access logging in Monday.
I'm very thankful for your answer.

Comment: We found few proccesses and killed them. After that output trafic became normal.
I asked our Java developer and as you told we were running tomcat as root on port 80. I suppose we were hacked. Now we're running root on 8080.
Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: Wow - glad you got to the bottom of it.